# What's the difference between Task.Wait() and ((IAsyncResult)Task).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Few days ago, I was exploring a piece of code on [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) in which waiting for a task was on the executing thread was done using `((IAsyncResult)Task).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` instead of `Task.Wait()`. The code was commented citing that `WaitOne()` has something to do with decreasing the chances of a deadlock compared with `Task.Wait()`. Unfortunately, I can't remember the precise expression they used in the comments or the piece of code I was exploring. Now, I'd like to understand the benefits I'd gain for preferring either of them to the other.

Comment: Use neither. `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` gives you more convenient exception handling if you *must* have a sync wait (in itself a smell). If you're OK with an `AggregateException` (or actually prefer or need it), use `Task.Wait()`. In highly specific scenarios I can think of ways in which explicitly getting a wait handle from the task might be a good idea, but this really needs context. Having the task allocate a native wait handle is not normally a good idea, deadlocks or no, and it should not be adopted as a default.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the context is that I've made custom worker that creates a separate thread and run queued work in appropriate order. Queued work is just a delegate, that can be a void, [return type], Task, or Task<T>. In either cases of the task, tasks should run and should be synchronously waited to ensure the integrity of execution order.

Comment: I know there are scenarios where a synchronous wait is appropriate (or at least necessary) -- I meant the context where accessing the `AsyncWaitHandle` explicitly was used (that is, the original spot in the reference source where you found it). That's the unusual case. A custom worker of the kind you describe would not qualify, unless you were doing things with binding handles to a thread pool. A wait handle wraps a kernel object and allocating one should be done sparingly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert would you recommend me any articles/books where I can read more about that?

Comment: I can at least refer you to Stephen "Mr. Async" Cleary's blog (disclaimer: nickname made up by me): on `AsyncWaitHandle` he writes ["Code using `AsyncWaitHandle` should be extremely, *extremely* rare."](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/10/a-tour-of-task-part-5-wait.html). Of course, the whole of his material on `Task`s is worth reading. The fact that `AsyncWaitHandle` allocates an object that must be disposed is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iasyncresult.asyncwaithandle), the fact that it's usually a kernel event object is an open secret.

Comment: It is fairly doubtful.  You have to keep in mind that the Microsofties had to make their code work with a preview version of the Task class.  Odd that you don't link to the code snippet btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Although I couldn't find the one I was looking at, I made a quick search and could find few scenarios in which `WaitOne` was used instead of `Wait`. [1](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,1378), [2](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,813), [3](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,818), [4](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,1406), (and more)